# How to determine how many subsets of a set contain a particular element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say set A contains 500,000 elements. Inside set A, there is a particular element, which we will call x. How do I go about finding the number of subsets of A that contain x?

Comment: Count the subsets of $A\setminus \{x\}$.

Comment: Alternately, note that there is a bijection between subsets that do contain $x$ and those that don't, given just by removing $x$.